# Understanding BIND_ADJUST_WITH_ACTIVITY, BIND_IMPORTANT and BIND_ABOVE_CLIENT

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service which is started from one of my apps activity, but can be used by multiple activities in the app. When an activity which uses the service binds to it I need to make the service work at the same performance rate as being part of the activity, other than that it doesn't need to be such high priority.

Now I have looked at the documentation and  found this 3 flags:

- BIND_ABOVE_CLIENT
- BIND_IMPORTANT
- BIND_ADJUST_WITH_ACTIVITY

If I understand correctly bind_above_client will make the service have actually higher priority than the activity, not sure if this is a desired case....

What I cannot really work out is BIND_IMPORTANT says it will raise the service to the same level as the activity, but so does the BIND_ADJUST_WITH_ACTIVITY

What is the difference between them?

I have read the documentation but I find it a bit ambiguous and not sure what is the difference between the 2.